# Abstract Class Initialization in C++

Tags: c++

In Java you can initialize an abstract class without the need of having a class that derives from it by just implementing the abstract method. Ex:

```
public abstract class A { public abstract void a(); }
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A b = new A() { @Override public void a() { System.out.println("Test"); } }
    }
}
```

My question is: can you do something like that in C++?

Comment: The duplicate is about 10 times more complicated than this simple question. A more concise answer would be: "No. But read more about C++11 lambdas."

Comment: It’s not needed in C++. In Java, anonymous classes were used to implement lambdas (before Java8, where lambdas were introduced into the language). In C++, you can use lambdas directly, no need to implement an abstract class.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I agree, which is why I’ve voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ does not support this.

But C++ uses less OOP in general (with "OOP" in the sense of "using virtual functions"). In particular, since C++11, **lambdas** provide a powerful alternative to many OOP-based patterns in Java.

Here is a very simple example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void f(std::function<void()> a)
{
    a();
}

int main()
{
    f([]() { std::cout << "Test\n"; });
}
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Operation>
void f(Operation operation)
{
    operation();
}

int main()
{
    f([]() { std::cout << "Test\n"; });
}
```

---

In fact, lambdas have become so popular in programming these days that Java 8 supports them too:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @Codorilla: The most commonly used definition of OOP in C++ involves the use of virtual functions. See the definition used by Bjarne himself at http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#oop. Lambdas do not have anything to do with virtual functions. And the new thing about lambdas is precisely the defining point of the Java feature the OP seeks to mimic: they are *anonymous*.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not allow instantiating abstract classes without deriving a non-abstract class from it.  It only allows you to derive the class “inline”, directly at the point of instantiation, which is known as *anonymous classes*.

You can achieve a similar effect in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

struct ABC
{
  virtual void f() = 0;
  virtual ~ABC() {}
};

int
main()
{
  struct : ABC { void f() override { std::cout << "okay\n"; } } anon {};
  anon.f();
}
```

Comment: I'd say it's a similar effect. You will have to name the instance.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm naming the *instance*, but not the *type*.  Unless I'm missing something, this is the same as what the OP is doing in the Java example.  I'm not sure how to create the object on the free store, however.

Comment: In Java, you don't name the instance either.

Comment: Or rather, you don't have to name it. The OP's naming of the instance somehow defeats the purpose of the pattern in Java. You'd normally pass an instance of `A` to some method like `someOtherMethod(new A() { @Override public void a() { System.out.println("Test"); } });`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Fair enough, I've adopted your wording.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply no.
the Java feature you are talking about called "Anonymous Classes" and this kind of feature simply does not exists in C++.

Comment: What would you call the solution from @5gon12eder?

Comment: he still has to call his instance in some name, therefore it's not really an alternative to Java anonymous classes